# Spring/Neo4J - Is impermanentGraphDatabase compatible with Transaction Annotation?

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-transactions, spring-data-neo4j

Firstly, I precise that I use Spring Data for Neo4J 2.2.0-release and Scala 2.10.

I'm building some tests in order to test my application services.

Here my different files in call order (I precise that its a conceptual sample but tested):

**MeetingServices.scala**

```
@Service
class MeetingServices {


  @Transactional
    def save(meeting: Meeting, creator: User): ValidationNel[MeetingFailure, Meeting] = {
      try {
        meetingRepository.save(meeting, creator).successNel[MeetingFailure]
      } catch {
        case e: Throwable => MeetingFailure("Fail to create the Meeting " + meeting + "for the user :" + creator, Some(e)).failNel[Meeting]
      }
    }
}
```

**Save method in MeetingRepository.scala:**

```
def save(meeting: Meeting, creator: User): Meeting = { //no need to declare a transaction since this method call is wrapped inside the previous save() method of MeetingServices 
    creator.participateIn(meeting)                                           
    meeting.creator = creator
    meetingRepository.save(meeting)
}
```

**Interesting excerpt of User.class:**

```
@RelatedTo(`type` = "PARTICIPATES_IN")
  val meetings: java.util.Set[Meeting] = new java.util.HashSet[Meeting]()


def participateIn(meeting: Meeting) = {
    meeting.creator = this   // since bidirectional relation
    meetings.add(meeting)    //#needs_transaction 
}
```

So what is the problem?:

In production, all works well. Transaction occurs and my meeting is persisted and linked with its creator (User neo4j-relationship).
But in my environment test, I've got this: `NotInTransactionException`. 
Why ?  Because at the line annotated with #needs_transaction (in excerpt above), the Relationship annotation expects a transaction and it sounds no transaction is created during tests.

I use two different application-context.xml for Spring configuration, one for my tests, the second for application in production.
The one used for tests is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">


    <neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService"/>


    <bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.test.ImpermanentGraphDatabase" />




    <neo4j:repositories base-package="repositories"/>


    <context:spring-configured/>


    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="controllers, services, models,repositories"/>


    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"/>


</beans>
```

The one I use in Production:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">




    <neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService"/>
    <bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="http://myUrl/db/data/"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="111111"/>
        <constructor-arg index="2" value="111111"/>
    </bean>




    <neo4j:repositories base-package="repositories" />


    <context:spring-configured/>


    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="controllers, applicationservices, models,repositories"/>


    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"/>


</beans>
```

It really seems that ImpermanentGraphDatabase isn't concerned with any transaction declared by Spring....
How could I be so sure?  Because I switched `application-context.xml` initially for tests by the one from production (using Neo4j REST calls) without touching anything in my test's code and everything works well.

Did I miss something?

Thanks in advance :)

**---------------EDIT------------**

Actually, it works only with Noe4j Rest calls. With an embedded database or an ImpermanentDatabase, the error occurs.

Answer (score 3):

There are no transactions in the REST API, each http request has its own transaction. The java-rest-binding uses a ?Null-Transaction(Manager)`.

How is your service instantiated / injected ? And how and where is it used? Perhaps you can share a sample project with a failing unit test on github?

You configuration looks correct, I assume it is something around how you have the service injected from Spring, so that the transaction aspects are not applied correctly.

Don't know if that helps you: http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/2012/03/29/neo4j-spring-data-scala/

Comment: I posted yesterday a more precise explanation of my issue here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/neo4j/Ru6J08F1np8   My service class (containing the `save` method) is annotated with @Service and is presents in the package applicationservices (so scanned by the component-scan of spring).

Comment: I put a demo of the issue here, for those who are interesting: https://github.com/mica16/TransactionNeo4JIssue.git